# Token based authentication with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django

I'm practicing through the django rest_framework documentation and struck at authentication, especially token based authentication. I'm able to create token for user which already created. Now the thing is how to give permissions to users add, delete, update the information by providing the token. I have done some stuff, below

models.py

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)

    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    highlighted = models.TextField(default = '')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

views.py

```
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer,UserSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import generics

from rest_framework import permissions
from snippets.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly

class SnippetList(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

class SnippetDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
    """
   # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        snippet.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                      IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style','owner')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Snippet.objects.all())

    #owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

ulrs.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from snippets import views
import rest_framework
#rfrom rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view()),

    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                               namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

Error:

```
>>> from snippets.models import Snippet
>>> from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
>>> from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
>>> from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
>>> snippet = Snippet(code='foo = "bar"\n')
>>> snippet.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/phygital/kiran/snippets/models.py", line 56, in save
    super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 820, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 859, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1060, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_snippet.owner_id
```

Comment: You must specify owner to Snippet model.
>>> snippet = Snippet(owner=owner, ....)
>>> snippet.save()
What is your exact question?

Comment: yes i need to add owner to Snippet classs

Comment: i need currently logged in user?

Comment: admin user is the user to get access through  token and views the data,update,delete data. and i created users class in models.py

Comment: You have error "IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_snippet.owner_id" its because you trying to create Snippet without owner. You can get current logged in user like this (in View): user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.id)

Comment: I think you can get the currently logged-in user from value of the `request.user` object

So, for instance `request.user.username` gives you the username of the currently logged in user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token Authentication using Django rest framework.

views.py

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class SampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

create Token for using in normal view or signal(post save method)

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
token = Token.objects.create(user=your instance)
```

Pass the parameter as the Token in the Header of the request, as said in [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication):

> For clients to authenticate, the token key should be included in the
>   `Authorization` HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string
>   literal "Token", with whitespace separating the two strings. For
>   example:
>
> `Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b`